# Get value from max(date) row in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. The first table is called as simas_barang and the second table is called as simas_mutasi.

simas_barang

| id | jenis | nama |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ATK DAN SEJENISNYA | KERTAS HVS |
| 2 | INVENTARIS | PRINTER L-3150 |
| 3 | ATK DAN SEJENISNYA | VIXAL |

simas_mutasi

| kode_barang | nama | tanggal | sisa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | vixal | 2022-06-02 | 10 |
| 1 | KERTAS HVS | 2022-06-02 | 10 |
| 3 | vixal | 2022-06-03 | 7 |
| 3 | vixal | 2022-06-09 | 9 |
| 3 | vixal | 2022-06-16 | 8 |

I want to get one **nama** from a new updated **tanggal**(date). So it's going to be like

| nama | tanggal | sisa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KERTAS HVS | 2022-06-02 | 10 |
| vixal | 2022-06-16 | 8 |

I tried to make a query but it didn't work

```
SELECT simas_barang.nama, max(simas_mutasi.tanggal), simas_mutasi.sisa
    FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi 
    INNER JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang
    ON simas_barang.id=simas_mutasi.kode_barang
    where (simas_barang.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA')
    and (tanggal >= '2022-06-01') and (tanggal <= '2022-06-31')
    group by simas_barang.nama, tanggal
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT` - _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Remove the other dbms tag.)

Comment: "I tried to make a query but it didn't work" - why does that mean? Had a syntax error? Returned the wrong results - if so what?

Comment: Your query selects from two tables, but there's only sample data for one of them. Make it easy to assist you, include a complete [mcve].

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; you'll need to (re)add the appropriate tag(s) in an [edit].

Comment: @jarlh I am using MySQL. I am sorry for making you confused.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY simas_barang.nama, simas_mutasi.sisa` and see what happens.

Comment: @jarlh it didn't catch one row of each nama from the updated date

Answer (score 0):

Order by the date in descending order and take the fist one:

```
SELECT simas_barang.nama, simas_mutasi.tanggal, simas_mutasi.sisa
FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi 
  INNER JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang ON simas_barang.id=simas_mutasi.kode_barang
WHERE simas_barang.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
AND tanggal between '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-31'
ORDER BY simas_mutasi.tanggal DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: hello :) I already edited the table